# Absolute element on top of fixed element?

Tags: html, css

Suppose I have the following:

```
<div class="bottom"></div>

<div class="top"></div>

.bottom {
   position: fixed;
   //...etc
}

.top {
   position: absolute;
   //...etc
}
```

How can I get `top` to always appear above `bottom` **on a mobile device**.  I know that just adding a z-index won't work because the elements will have their own stacking contexts.  I need bottom to be fixed (or act like fixed) and I need top to be absolute (or act like absolute).

Comment: Is the content of .bottom going to be HTML, or just an image?

Comment: HTML is what it is going to be

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to put your fixed positioned element in a wrapper which needs to form a new stacking context and will be the parent of your fixed element which must be in the same stacking context. This could be achieved by relative positioning the wrapper element.

Although fixed positioned elements are layed out with respect to the viewport, they still keep the stack (and `z-index`) order of their parent element.

Sounds a bit confusing ..., but here is a [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Netsurfer/E9qV7/) to illustrate what I tried to explain above.

Answer (score -2):

If bottom should be on the absolute bottom and top on top, then use:

```
.bottom {
   position: fixed;
   bottom:0px;
   //...etc
}

.top {
   position: absolute;
   top:0px;
   //...etc
}
```

**EDIT:** I may have misunderstood your question. If you mean above in the z-axis, it might be worth it to make it so all the z-values of all the elements in top are larger than all of the z-values of all the elements in bottom.

Comment: I do mean above in the z-axis, but unfortunately merely setting the z-index won't work because fixed and absolute are in different stacking contexts